# Implementing 'Caps Lock On' and 'Show Password' in hosted login page

Tags: angularjs, auth0

I'm building an application using AngularJS and usin Auth0 for authentication.

I wish to let the user know when *Caps Lock* is enabled. Same as when we log into Windows; the yellow string that says `Caps Lock is on`. So that he doesn't waste his time typing-in his password in caps.

I also wish to have a functionality which would let user see his password while typing (*Show Password*).

I went to the Auth0 customization page and could not find any property that I can put on in `window.Auth0.signIn({});` to observe the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

For angular.js I used this neat thing:

https://github.com/FabioMR/ng-caps-lock

Comment: Thanks for answering. But we cannot access Auth0's login page code. I wish to show this message right below the password field. I cannot paste a html code squarely. We can only customize the login page of Auth0. I am expecting some property that I need to put on to have the effect.

Comment: Can you add a javscript in that page?

Comment: Of course not. We just call `window.Auth0.signIn` to have the login page materialize.

Answer (score 0):

The [Auth0 hosted login page](https://auth0.com/docs/hosted-pages/login), by default, uses [Lock](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock) to provide the authentication process. There is some degree of [customization that you can perform simply by configuring Lock](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization) itself.

However, for complete control of the authentication experience you can fully customize the login page, including providing authentication through other means than Lock. In this scenario, you'll be able to have the exact UX that you want and meet your requirements for a CAPS LOCK indicator and show password option.